# Parsing my Nested JSON from strapi (localhost) to flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, http, strapi, flutter-bloc

Here is my json

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "createdAt": "2023-07-14T13:04:00.394Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-07-14T13:04:03.572Z",
            "publishedAt": "2023-07-14T13:04:03.564Z",
            "locale": "en",
            "Title": "AWS Job Ready course",
            "Description": "Amazon Web Services, Inc. is a subsidiary of Amazon that provides on-demand cloud computing platforms and APIs to individuals, companies, and governments, on a metered, pay-as-you-go basis. Oftentimes, clients will use this in combination with autoscaling.",
            "Order": 1,
            "CoverPic": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "awscoursebanner.jpg",
                "alternativeText": null,
                "caption": null,
                "width": 650,
                "height": 345,
                "formats": {
                    "small": {
                        "ext": ".jpg",
                        "url": "/uploads/small_awscoursebanner_fbe397f8d5.jpg",
                        "hash": "small_awscoursebanner_fbe397f8d5",
                        "mime": "image/jpeg",
                        "name": "small_awscoursebanner.jpg",
                        "path": null,
                        "size": 15.2,
                        "width": 500,
                        "height": 265
                    },
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "ext": ".jpg",
                        "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_awscoursebanner_fbe397f8d5.jpg",
                        "hash": "thumbnail_awscoursebanner_fbe397f8d5",
                        "mime": "image/jpeg",
                        "name": "thumbnail_awscoursebanner.jpg",
                        "path": null,
                        "size": 5.15,
                        "width": 245,
                        "height": 130
                    }
                },
                "hash": "awscoursebanner_fbe397f8d5",
                "ext": ".jpg",
                "mime": "image/jpeg",
                "size": 22.33,
                "url": "/uploads/awscoursebanner_fbe397f8d5.jpg",
                "previewUrl": null,
                "provider": "local",
                "provider_metadata": null,
                "createdAt": "2023-07-14T13:03:24.800Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-07-14T13:03:24.800Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the model I generated from json to dart site

```
class CoursesModel {
  List<Data>? data;
  Meta? meta;

  CoursesModel({this.data, this.meta});

  CoursesModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(new Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    meta = json['meta'] != null ? new Meta.fromJson(json['meta']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.meta != null) {
      data['meta'] = this.meta!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int? id;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  String? publishedAt;
  String? locale;
  String? title;
  String? description;
  int? order;
  CoverPic? coverPic;

  Data(
      {this.id,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt,
      this.publishedAt,
      this.locale,
      this.title,
      this.description,
      this.order,
      this.coverPic});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    createdAt = json['createdAt'];
    updatedAt = json['updatedAt'];
    publishedAt = json['publishedAt'];
    locale = json['locale'];
    title = json['Title'];
    description = json['Description'];
    order = json['Order'];
    coverPic = json['CoverPic'] != null
        ? new CoverPic.fromJson(json['CoverPic'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['createdAt'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updatedAt'] = this.updatedAt;
    data['publishedAt'] = this.publishedAt;
    data['locale'] = this.locale;
    data['Title'] = this.title;
    data['Description'] = this.description;
    data['Order'] = this.order;
    if (this.coverPic != null) {
      data['CoverPic'] = this.coverPic!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class CoverPic {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  Null? alternativeText;
  Null? caption;
  int? width;
  int? height;
  Formats? formats;
  String? hash;
  String? ext;
  String? mime;
  double? size;
  String? url;
  Null? previewUrl;
  String? provider;
  Null? providerMetadata;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  CoverPic(
      {this.id,
      this.name,
      this.alternativeText,
      this.caption,
      this.width,
      this.height,
      this.formats,
      this.hash,
      this.ext,
      this.mime,
      this.size,
      this.url,
      this.previewUrl,
      this.provider,
      this.providerMetadata,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  CoverPic.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    alternativeText = json['alternativeText'];
    caption = json['caption'];
    width = json['width'];
    height = json['height'];
    formats =
        json['formats'] != null ? new Formats.fromJson(json['formats']) : null;
    hash = json['hash'];
    ext = json['ext'];
    mime = json['mime'];
    size = json['size'];
    url = json['url'];
    previewUrl = json['previewUrl'];
    provider = json['provider'];
    providerMetadata = json['provider_metadata'];
    createdAt = json['createdAt'];
    updatedAt = json['updatedAt'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['alternativeText'] = this.alternativeText;
    data['caption'] = this.caption;
    data['width'] = this.width;
    data['height'] = this.height;
    if (this.formats != null) {
      data['formats'] = this.formats!.toJson();
    }
    data['hash'] = this.hash;
    data['ext'] = this.ext;
    data['mime'] = this.mime;
    data['size'] = this.size;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['previewUrl'] = this.previewUrl;
    data['provider'] = this.provider;
    data['provider_metadata'] = this.providerMetadata;
    data['createdAt'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updatedAt'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}

class Formats {
  Small? small;
  Small? thumbnail;

  Formats({this.small, this.thumbnail});

  Formats.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    small = json['small'] != null ? new Small.fromJson(json['small']) : null;
    thumbnail = json['thumbnail'] != null
        ? new Small.fromJson(json['thumbnail'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.small != null) {
      data['small'] = this.small!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.thumbnail != null) {
      data['thumbnail'] = this.thumbnail!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Small {
  String? ext;
  String? url;
  String? hash;
  String? mime;
  String? name;
  Null? path;
  double? size;
  int? width;
  int? height;

  Small(
      {this.ext,
      this.url,
      this.hash,
      this.mime,
      this.name,
      this.path,
      this.size,
      this.width,
      this.height});

  Small.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    ext = json['ext'];
    url = json['url'];
    hash = json['hash'];
    mime = json['mime'];
    name = json['name'];
    path = json['path'];
    size = json['size'];
    width = json['width'];
    height = json['height'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['ext'] = this.ext;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['hash'] = this.hash;
    data['mime'] = this.mime;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['path'] = this.path;
    data['size'] = this.size;
    data['width'] = this.width;
    data['height'] = this.height;
    return data;
  }
}

class Meta {
  Pagination? pagination;

  Meta({this.pagination});

  Meta.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    pagination = json['pagination'] != null
        ? new Pagination.fromJson(json['pagination'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.pagination != null) {
      data['pagination'] = this.pagination!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Pagination {
  int? page;
  int? pageSize;
  int? pageCount;
  int? total;

  Pagination({this.page, this.pageSize, this.pageCount, this.total});

  Pagination.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    page = json['page'];
    pageSize = json['pageSize'];
    pageCount = json['pageCount'];
    total = json['total'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['page'] = this.page;
    data['pageSize'] = this.pageSize;
    data['pageCount'] = this.pageCount;
    data['total'] = this.total;
    return data;
  }
}
```

This is the bloc code for using http

```
class CoursesBloc extends Bloc<CoursesEvent, CoursesState> {
  CoursesBloc() : super(CoursesInitial()) {
    on<CoursesInitialEvent>(coursesInitialEvent);
    on<CourseCardNavigateEvent>(courseCardNavigateEvent);
  }
  FutureOr<void> coursesInitialEvent(
      CoursesInitialEvent event, Emitter<CoursesState> emit) async {
    var client = http.Client();

    List<Data> datums = [];
    try{
      var response = await client.get(Uri.parse('http://192.168.66.1:1337/api/courses?populate=CoverPic'));
      List result = jsonDecode(response.body);
      for(var i=0; i<result.length;i++)
        {
          Data datum = Data.fromJson(result[i]);
          datums.add(datum);
        }

      print(datums);
      emit(CoursesLoadedSuccessState(datums));
    }
        catch(e){
      log(e.toString());
        }
  }

}
```

The error I get is:

```
[log] type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'
```

I felt it was with the Coverpic class being called in the Map, so i used

"http://192.168.66.1:1337/api/courses" instead as it wont populate CoverPic, but I end up with the same error

Comment: I am quite new to flutter bloc and strapi please do help

Comment: That error has to have an associated line of code with it.  But somewhere, you're expecting a List but it's actually a Map, so you have to make sure your decoding is perfectly aligned with the JSON you're getting in.

Comment: I copied the old version of bloc.dart code, I was calling The Data class in the Courses Model which I wrote it as Datum in the one I posted

Comment: You aren't showing the definition of the Datum class yet.  Or maybe you're saying that's the same as the Data class in the other code.  If that's the case, please fix your code so it all works together.

Comment: Also, your top-level use of "result" presumes a List at the top, but the JSON sample you included was a Map at the top.  Please show real values and code.

Comment: just updated it the only change was the class name is Data, the screen doesn't load at all, I copied the exact code which I had. Do I Use Map directly instead of lists then? in the line  "List<Data> datums = [];" and "List result = jsonDecode(response.body);". I have no clue  how to do it, please if you can point me to a source to learn or a solution it would be of great help

Comment: There are examples of decoding JSON and turning them into Dart objects in the dart codelabs.  And plenty of them all over the net.

Comment: I did check the net, from few days for an answer. So had to ask it here, will let you know if i find anything thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response body is a map. To access the data list, you need to use key `data`

```dart
List result = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
```

You can check [this](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-project-Helper/blob/c963c504996a6c3e75b4ba6b0781d0aebae52b34/jsonFormating/sample1.dart#L47) example.

Comment: A simple solution worked me up for days, thanks for the example understood the concept as well